# php xml string getting attribute uses namespace

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML file which uses namespaces.

When I use the following php function, it doesn't return the attributes for aws:Country Code

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response,null,false,
                            'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11')
```

So I was wondering.  How can I pull out the Country Code attribute?  Do I need to create a special function?  The following is a string returned a curl call.

```
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
<aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
<aws:OperationRequest><aws:RequestId>e3459429-82f5-f598-0219-18a8056cad27</aws:RequestId>
</aws:OperationRequest>

<aws:UrlInfoResult>

<aws:Alexa>

<aws:TrafficData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">samplesite.com</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:Rank>47216</aws:Rank>
      <aws:RankByCountry>
         <aws:Country Code="US">

            <aws:Rank>11438</aws:Rank>
            <aws:Contribution>
              <aws:PageViews>72.5%</aws:PageViews>
              <aws:Users>76.4%</aws:Users>
            </aws:Contribution>
      </aws:Country>
      <aws:Country Code="IN">
        <aws:Rank>45749</aws:Rank>
        <aws:Contribution>
          <aws:PageViews>17.0%</aws:PageViews>
          <aws:Users>7.5%</aws:Users>
        </aws:Contribution>
     </aws:Country>
    </aws:RankByCountry>
</aws:TrafficData>
</aws:Alexa>
</aws:UrlInfoResult>
</aws:Response>
</aws:UrlInfoResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$xml=<<<EOF
<aws:UrlInfoResponse xmlns:aws="http://alexa.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
<aws:Response xmlns:aws="http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11">
<aws:OperationRequest><aws:RequestId>e3459429-82f5-f598-0219-18a8056cad27</aws:RequestId>
</aws:OperationRequest>

<aws:UrlInfoResult>

<aws:Alexa>

<aws:TrafficData>
    <aws:DataUrl type="canonical">samplesite.com</aws:DataUrl>
    <aws:Rank>47216</aws:Rank>
      <aws:RankByCountry>
     <aws:Country Code="US">

        <aws:Rank>11438</aws:Rank>
        <aws:Contribution>
          <aws:PageViews>72.5%</aws:PageViews>
          <aws:Users>76.4%</aws:Users>
        </aws:Contribution>
      </aws:Country>
      <aws:Country Code="IN">
    <aws:Rank>45749</aws:Rank>
    <aws:Contribution>
      <aws:PageViews>17.0%</aws:PageViews>
      <aws:Users>7.5%</aws:Users>
    </aws:Contribution>
     </aws:Country>
    </aws:RankByCountry>
</aws:TrafficData>
</aws:Alexa>
</aws:UrlInfoResult>
</aws:Response>
</aws:UrlInfoResponse>
EOF;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, null, false, 'http://awis.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-07-11');
foreach($sxe->xpath('//*[@Code]') as $node) {
        if($node->getName() != 'Country') continue;
        echo $node->attributes()->Code . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me because $xml doesn't return the attributes.  How do I read it to traverse the xml file to get the tags and the attributes..my solution just gets the tags.  Your solution doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: thanks that works..when I tried it just with what you sent it didn't..now it works perfectly.